# How to get entity from block after it was modified inside block AutoCAD C#

Tags: c#, autocad-plugin

I am working on AutoCAD plugin and at some point I need to get Entity which has been modified inside block. Block contains only one entity. I made event handler for appropriate BlockTableRecord which responces to 'Modified' event. I want to get single entity that has been modified, but all I get through this method, is Entity from model space which is previous version of needed entity.
This is how I planned to get my Entity:

```
public static Entity GetEntityFromBlock(HooverSpace.Map.WorkSpace ws, BlockReference br, ObjectId entId)
        {
            Entity ent = null;

            ObjectId blockId;

            if (ws.acBlkTbl.Has(br.Name))
                blockId = ws.acBlkTbl[br.Name];
            else
                return null;

            Entity searchEnt = (Entity)entId.GetObject(OpenMode.ForRead);

            BlockTableRecord btr = (BlockTableRecord)ws.acTrans.GetObject(blockId, OpenMode.ForRead);

            foreach (ObjectId blkEntId in btr)
            {
                Entity blockEnt = (Entity)ws.acTrans.GetObject(blkEntId, OpenMode.ForWrite);
                if (blockEnt.BlockName == btr.Name && blockEnt.Layer == searchEnt.Layer)
                {
                    ent = blockEnt.Clone() as Entity;
                    break;
                }
                    
            }

            ent.TransformBy(br.BlockTransform);
            return ent;
        }
```

I am stuck on this issue and would be very glad if someone will help me.

Edit:
I resolved this issue by getting BlockTableRecord from `br.BlockTableRecord` id. Thanks everyone!

Comment: You need the instance of the entity obj that contains the data.  The error is not in the code posted but the method that made the call.  The object has to be inside the program and not a file.

Answer (score 0):

Try use
`var _BTR = ws.acTrans.GetObject(br.BlockTableRecord, OpenMode.ForRead) as BlockTableRecord;`
to resolve your problem